# Open url in specific browser locally

Tags: vb.net

I have created a website, with a link button that opens a link in IE, and when I run the program locally,

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", myUrl)
```

works just fine.

However - when I have published my website and run the program from the webserver, every click on my link button will open IE - on the webserver...

Is there a way to make a specific browser open on the local machine?

Comment: Of course it opens on the server.  That's where the VB code is executed.  If you want to do something at the client, you need to do it in client-side code, i.e. JavaScript. Running a specific application from a browser is a much bigger deal because there are significant security concerns.

Comment: What if the user isn't using a Windows machine?

Comment: How user triggers the action (Proces...)?

Comment: It is being triggered from our CRM-system. You push a button that fires an url command. And our customer service all use windows machines, so that will not be a problem :-) The issue here is that the webapplication on that particular url only works in IE, and that is not something I can change.